# Combining 2 Options into 1

Tags: scala, scala-option

Is there a predefined function x in Scala that combine 2 Options so that

```
Some(a) x None => Some(a)
None x Some(b) => Some(b)
None x None => None
```

Comment: What about when you have `Some(a)` and `Some(b)`?

Comment: That case can't happen in what I'm doing, so I don't care what the result is.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, this is the `orElse` method. It chooses the first defined value, or `None` if neither is defined.

```
scala> Some(1) orElse None
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> None orElse Some(1)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> None orElse None
res2: Option[Nothing] = None

scala> Some(1) orElse Some(2)
res3: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not hard to do it by hand:

```
scala> val a = Some(1)
a: Some[Int] = Some(1)

scala> val b = Some(2)
b: Some[Int] = Some(2)

scala> Seq(a,b).flatten.headOption
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Comment: Or just `(a ++ b).headOption`.

Answer (score 3):

In the question comments, you mention you can't have `Some(a)` and `Some(b)`, so what you really have is `Option[Either[Int,Int]]`. In that case, you can use `x.map(_.merge)` to get back to `Option[Int]`, eg

```
scala> val x:Option[Either[Int,Int]] = Some(Left(2))
x: Option[Either[Int,Int]] = Some(Left(2))

scala> x.map(_.merge)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

Comment: This is a very good point. It's suspicious to be using a type which so obviously has inhabitants that "can't happen"

Comment: this might not work out so well though if he has two `Option[T]` returning functions though, or would it?

Comment: My point was more that *if* the two `Some` cases *can't* happen, then it would be better to encode that in the type system. If there are 2 `Option[T]` values, then it must be assumed that they can both be `Some`. The `orElse` answer that Ben gave prioritises one option over the other, which may be valid. Using `Option[Either[T,T]]` though removes the need to make that decision.